# How to label a code section in Sweave

Tags: r, labels, sweave

I'm new to sweave and was wondering what is the appropriate way to label a code section. For example, if I have:

```
<<echo= true>>=
x<-5
y<-x+5
@
```

How would I get it to put a either above it or below it, with something like "Code Example 1". I would like something similar to how you can label figures or tables in LaTeX.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 7):

In LaTeX captions can be used within float environments like figures or tables.
So if your R output is e.g. a figure you can enclose it in a figure environment:

```
\begin{figure}

<<fig=TRUE, echo=FALSE, eps=TRUE>>=
  data(iris)
  boxplot(iris[,2]~iris[,5])
@

\caption{A boxplot of the famous Fisher data set.}
\end{figure}
```

If you want your R-Code as a float environment (with the possibility to use \caption) you will have to define your own float environment. Have a look at [LaTeX WikiBook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Custom_Floats). Something like the following will do it:

In your document preamble:

```
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{rcode}{h!t}{rcode}
\floatname{rcode}{Code Example}
```

Then in your document body:

```
\begin{rcode}
<<echo=true>>=
x<-5
y<-x+5
@
\caption{This code shows something.}
\end{rcode}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<<label = MyChunk, echo= true>>=
x<-5
y<-x+5
@
```

Comment: I did, it has no effect!

Comment: That wasn't what the OP meant by label the chunk. Yours is the correct answer to a different Q. See the Answer of Stefan Pointner for what appears to have been wanted.